# Moodle 2.9 super slow on wamp

Tags: wamp, moodle

I have a Moodle platform on WAMP architecture (2 app servers and 1 db server,  all working with the same shared directory for moodle file). 
Php 5.5.12
Apache 2.4.9
Mysql 5.6.17
Win server 2012r2

The site is in an internal, closed, network,  whereas users are identified through active directory (ldap tree).

The site is very slow.  Every time we are trying to enter the site,  it takes around 30 seconds to load the page, and these are the first network entries on chrome console:

Index.php, status 303, initiator-other, size 612b, time 23 sec

Index.php?testsession=11, status 303, initiator- http://mooc/login/index.php, size 429b, time 763 ms

mooc, status 200, initiator- http : // mooc / login / index.php?testsession=11, size 38kb, time 4 sec

30 seconds thia part alone.

As some of you might notice,  the site's address  is http://mooc/

This testsession=11 seems suspicious, isn't it?

What do you say?

Thanks!

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll post over there to